# creating knockout template for table row

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-templating

I'm trying to create a knockout template that should generate a table row for each row in the knockout array. 
When I add the below code it tells me "element script cannot be nested inside element table"

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>ID#</th>
    <th>Name</th>
</tr>
<tr data-bind="template: { name: 'EmployeeTemplate', foreach: EmployeesArray }"></tr>
<script type="text/html" id="EmployeeTemplate">
    <td>234567899874</td>
    <td>Mr. Test </td>
</script>
```

How can I resolve this using knockout templates?  I'm basing it off [this](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) link.

Comment: Have you tried moving the template _outside_ of the table?

Comment: but don't I need it in the table if I want it to be for the tr element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script type="text/html" id="templateName">
    <td data-bind="text: Property"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: Property"></td>
</script>   

<tbody data-bind="foreach: data">
  <tr data-bind="template: { name: 'templateName', data: $data }"></tr>
</tbody>
```

This should work.

Comment: in order to use the templates I need to put a script tag - I'm basing it off of this link: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html

Comment: and then I should move the script tags out of the table?